# How to handle MongoDB array with jQuery each?

Tags: jquery, arrays, mongodb, each

**MongoDB Schema**

```
{
"title": "my_title",
"myArray": ["1","2","3","4","5"]
}
```

**Firebug Response**

```
{"myArray": ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]}
```

**Desired Behaviour**

The value of `data-thing` and the first `li class` are dynamic, where the values come from a database array.  Iterating over this array generates a list of `li`'s with dynamic values.

Generated HTML should be:

```
<li data-thing="1" class="prefix_1">
<ul class="nested">
<li class="hidden_li">
<p class="thing2">text</p>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
```

Followed by:

```
 <li data-thing="2" class="prefix_2"> etc.
```

**jQuery**

```
$.getJSON("/path", {cid: href, format: 'json'}, function(myArray){
$.each(myArray, function(k,v) {
$("ul.class1").append("<li data-thing=\"" + v + "\" class=\"prefix_" + v + "\"><ul class=\"nested\"><li class=\"hidden_li\"><p class=\"thing2\">text</p></li></ul></li>");
});
})
```

**Current Behaviour**

```
 <li class="prefix_1,2,3,4,5" data-thing="1,2,3,4,5">
 <ul class="nested">
 <li class="hidden_li">
 <p class="thing2">text</p>
 </li>
 </ul>
 </li>
```

**jsFiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/rwone/M9e8N/4/

(Shows desired results from static array).

**Problem**

I get the desired behaviour when using a static array, but when I use `getJSON()` to get the array from the database I am not getting the desired results.

I think therefore I am referencing the array incorrectly in the jQuery and the iteration is not occurring as expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

```
$.each(myArray.myArray, function(k,v) { ...
```

I had to reference the key name in the database document.

The first `myArray` is the name of the results returned to `getJSON()`, the second `.myArray` is the reference to the key name in the database document.